# A question about the Desargues Configuration

Tags: graph-theory

What is an intersection graph? And how can I construct the intersection graph of the Desargues Configuration?

I'm currently trying to show that the intersection graph of the Desargues Configuration is isomorphic to another graph, but I want to visualize both graphs before proceeding.

(Note: The Desargues Configuration is a configuration of 10 points and ten lines, with three points per line and three lines per point. Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues_configuration for further information)

Comment: It might help many Readers to see a picture of the Desargues configuration as [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues_configuration) illustrates.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As stated in the comment by Morgan Rodgers, the lines in Desargues Configuration are the vertices in your intersection graph, and adjacency is defined by intersection of lines. So it should end up as a 6-regular graph on 10 vertices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the igraph library in R to find the plot.

Since the intersection graph of the Desargues Configuration is isomorphic to the line graph of $K_5$, you can use the following code to produce the image below:

```
library(igraph)

g <- make_full_graph(5)
L <- make_line_graph(g)
plot.igraph(L)
```

It's a bit ugly but will do the trick.

[image]

Here is the output of `make_line_graph(g)` to help you see the edges:

```
H 609c465 U--- 10 30 -- Line graph
+ attr: name (g/c)
+ edges from 609c465:
 [1] 1-- 2 1-- 3 2-- 3 1-- 4 2-- 4 3-- 4 2-- 5 1-- 5 3-- 6 1-- 6 5-- 6 4-- 7
[13] 1-- 7 5-- 7 6-- 7 3-- 8 6-- 8 2-- 8 5-- 8 4-- 9 7-- 9 2-- 9 5-- 9 8-- 9
[25] 4--10 7--10 9--10 3--10 6--10 8--10
```

Alternatively, you can arrive at the same graph by taking the complement of the famous Petersen Graph.

```
library(igraph)

g <- make_graph("petersen")
C <- complementer(g)
plot.igraph(C)
```